# What does Shinobi shout?

Tags: shinobi, shadow-dancer-the-secret-of-shinobi

I’m playing the *Shinobi* saga again, after more than 30 years. Do you know what he shouts while doing his special move? It sounds something like "hoo-ree-ah", but probably it's something meaningful.

[In *Shinobi 1*, at around 10:35](https://youtu.be/tyoQ7m6BGZU?t=635):

[In *Shadow Dancer: The Secret of Shinobi*, at around 3:30](https://youtu.be/GpZBhEgHZ28?t=210):

Comment: What kind of "source" are you even looking for, when you've already put the videos with it? Are you expecting the script or something? I'm 99% sure no one can provide that...

Comment: I'm expecting something more than "it sounds like something that doesn't mean anything": maybe someone has more information about that. Is this a problem for you?

Comment: No it isn't, but I'd say any native Japanese speaker would agree with my sentiment (perhaps with a bit of change like おりゃあ or like that; it also means nothing other than shout).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From native Japanese speaker's perspective, Shinobi 1's voice sounds like "とりゃあー！"(toryaa) which means absolutely nothing other than shout.

As for the Shadow Dancer, that also sounds like "うりゃあー！"(uryaa) or something like that, and this one also means absolutely nothing other than shout.

Comment: Is it the actual word "shout" or just like an onomatopoeia?

Comment: @TimmyJim No, actual word for "shout" would be "叫ぶ(sakebu)", let's just say it's some variations of the shouting, like war cry - so yeah I guess it's just like an onomatopoeia.